Not able to export to gltf
I am not able to export my object to gltf. getting some python error. I have used transparent bsdf material, is that causing the issue?
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py", line 512, in execute
    from .blender.exp import gltf2_blender_export
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_export.py", line 22, in <module>
    from io_scene_gltf2.blender.exp import gltf2_blender_gather
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 19, in <module>
    from io_scene_gltf2.blender.exp import gltf2_blender_gather_nodes
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 24, in <module>
    from io_scene_gltf2.blender.exp import gltf2_blender_gather_mesh
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 20, in <module>
    from io_scene_gltf2.blender.exp import gltf2_blender_gather_primitives
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 17, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

location: <unknown location>:-1

```


Most people are able to export GLTF from Blender just fine. You have not provided any information about what or how you are trying to export or any details about the context of the problem. What OS are you using? What Blender version? It says numpy module cannot be found, so there is likely something unusual about how Blender's Python functions. Numpy comes with Python bundled with Blender as far as I know, so there must be something unusual about how Blender and its Python are installed and set up on your system. How did you install Blender? Have you tried portable version?
